# Array loop - Converting everything to string

Tags: php, arrays, casting

OK so i am simply trying to create an array using a loop but keep the type. For some reason, when i use $array[] = .. it is casting everyting to a string. My code looks like:

```
foreach ($value as $val){
   $array[] .= (int)$val
}
```

when I var dump, everything is of type string even though i have explicitly told it to be an integer. It keeps putting my number in quotes like this "7".

```
["var1"]=> string(1) "7" 
["var2"]=> string(0) "" 
...
```

and I want it to be

```
["var1"]=> int(1) 7 
["var2"]=> int(0) null
```

or something like that. Im trying to pass information to my database via this array and it keeps converting everything to string or empty string which is overriding my null values. Thank you.

Comment: You know that `.=` means concatenation, right?

Comment: try `=` instead of `.=`

Comment: OMG! Im a newbie and thought that when .= was used to create an array that that meant keep adding to the array smh. I removed the .= and used = and it'w working just fine now. Thank you so much!!!